# How to change UIPageControl dot not only when scrollView did end decelerating?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uipagecontrol

I have created a User Onboarding as a `Collection View` with 2 items.

The `Collection View` has a `UIPageControl` which shows an active page user currently on.

The problem is I can change the state of active `UIPageControl` dot only when the transition is ended, after user swiped to the next\previous screen.

This is how it looks now: [GIF](https://cln.sh/OGKRg2)

I want the behaviour so when you start to swipe `UIPageControl` should already change its active dot onto the next\previous one without me necessarily ending the swipe (lift the finger).

You can check what I want on the gif: [GIF](https://cln.sh/kBr8Ml)

Here is how I change the `UIPageControl` dot now:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let width = scrollView.frame.width
    currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / width)
    pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
}
```

How my code should be modified, which method to use to achieve the behaviour? I couldn't find any similar questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question...

- you have only TWO cells (pages)
- you want the page control to reflect which page is *most* visible

Instead of `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, implement:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let fw = scrollView.frame.width
    // get the percentage scrolled
    let pct = scrollView.contentOffset.x / fw
    // if it's less-than 50%, we're at page 0
    // else, we're at page 1
    pageControl.currentPage = pct < 0.5 ? 0 : 1
}
```

Comment: Hi DonMag! Thank you, that helped a lot!